# Exclude entities from Legend in Sankey Diagram

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js

I have a Sankey chart with a beginning and end node.
When I create a legend using the function below.

I would like to FILTER out particular nodes from the legend (the first and end nodes).

The node names will ALWAYS be the same, but as the number of nodes changes dynamically their index will be different.

Is this possible, or very complicated?

Can I apply a filter or exclusion function to the

```js
svg.selectAll('.legendOrdinal .cell')
                    .attr('transform', function(d,i) {
                        // make 2 column legend
                        var row = Math.floor(i / items_in_row) * element[0].offsetWidth/2;
                        return 'translate(' + row +',' + (i % items_in_row) * 21 + ')';
                    })
```

```js
           function render_legend(nodes) {
                var items_in_row = Math.ceil(nodes.length/2);

                d3.select(element[0]).select('#legend').remove();
                var svg = d3.select(element[0])
                    .append("svg")
                        .attr('width', '100%')
                        .attr('height', ((items_in_row+1) * 25) + 'px')
                        .attr('id', 'legend');

                var ordinal = d3.scale.ordinal()
                    .domain(nodes.map(function(d) {
                        return d.name;
                    }))
                    .range(color.range());

                // append legend text
                if (nodes.length != 0) {
                svg.append('text')
                    .attr('x', 15)
                    .attr('y', 15)
                    .text('Enabling infrastructure investments:');
                };

                svg.append("g")
                    .attr("class", "legendOrdinal")
                    .attr("transform", "translate(20, 40)");

                var legendOrdinal = d3.legend.color()
                    .shape("path", d3.svg.symbol().type("circle").size(200)())
                    .shapePadding(5)
                    .scale(ordinal);

                svg.select(".legendOrdinal")
                    .call(legendOrdinal);

                svg.selectAll('.legendOrdinal .cell')
                    .attr('transform', function(d,i) {
                        // make 2 column legend
                        var row = Math.floor(i / items_in_row) * element[0].offsetWidth/2;
                        return 'translate(' + row +',' + (i % items_in_row) * 21 + ')';
                    })
            };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you apply filtering to the `domain` call?

```
.domain(nodes.filter(function(d, i) {return i > 0 && i < N - 1; /*or anything else */})
             .map(function(d) {
                    return d.name;
                }))
```